# использование хелпера form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Что-то я совсем запутался... использую хелпер `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for @foods do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

в контроллере определен `@foods` как:

```
def index
  @foods = Food.all
end
```

миграция определена как:

```
create_table "foods", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

модель определена как:

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

так рельсы (gem 'rails', '4.2.6') на руби ( ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]  ) выдают:

undefined method `to_key' for "#Food::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000002af6f98"
Did you mean?  to_query
               to_ary

я что не так делаю???

Comment: Примерно всё. Приведённо вы сделали форму для `Food.all`. Какой смысл вы в это вкладывали?

Comment: Ау? Вы ещё здесь?

Answer (score 1):

Если форма выводится в роуте соответствующем методу `index`, то ошибка заключается в том, что вместо создания одной новой модели

```
@food = Food.new
```

или поиска уже существующей записи

```
@food = Food.find(params[:id])
```

Вы извлекаете все записи, соответствующие модели `Food`

```
@foods = Food.all
```

У вас получается не объект `Food`, который ждет хелпер `from_for`, а коллекция `ActiveRecord::Relation`, которая форма не может обработать. В `from_for` следует передавать лишь какой-то один объект.